# How to dynamically update ToggleButton status inside Dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a Dialog that has a ToggleButton to trigger Wifi on/off and is working fine. I have 1 issue if the Wifi status is triggle outside my app such as user toggle in system settings, how do I update it dynamically?

Is there some example to do something like this?

Cheers.

Comment: So, whats the problem is in? In determining if wifi is on/off, or in actually switching your ToggleButton?

Comment: why are you not able to toggle?

Comment: I can toggle but I want to change dynamically. Eg. If I am in my app, I toggle Wifi ON, my app will switch the Wifi off. This is good but if I switch to Android setting to turn off and return to my app. The Wifi toggle button will be ON instead of OFF unless I dismiss the dialog and recreate it. In view, I use UIThread to do this but wonder how to do it for dialog?

Answer (score 0):

If you have handle for the dialog, then you can call

```
ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton) dialog.findViewByID([id of togglebutton]);
tb.setchecked(toggle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should register [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for [android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) (and may be others), and toggle your button in this reciever.

See example [here](http://silverballsoftware.com/android-monitor-wifi-state-with-broadcastreceiver).